Using community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync module in ansible
To manage an OpenShift cluster, I want to use community.okd collection of Ansible, more precisely the module openshift_adm_groups_sync. the same module exist in "Openshift" collection too.
ref: community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync module – Sync OpenShift Groups with records from an external provider.
Ansible Collections
Automation-Hub
My purpose is to Sync an LDAP group with Openshift cluster. Ldap group exist already in Openshift and manual synchronization works. When I want to do that with ansible, I get errors.
Here is my ansible environment:
ansible [core 2.16.3]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 3.12.3 (main, Jun 19 2024, 10:06:03) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-22)] (/usr/bin/python3.12)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True


Collections already installed:
ansible-galaxy collection list -p /usr/share/ansible/collections

# /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections
Collection       Version
---------------- -------
ansible.posix    1.5.4
community.okd    4.0.0
kubernetes.core  5.0.0

# /usr/share/ansible/collections/ansible_collections
Collection       Version
---------------- -------
kubernetes.core  5.0.0
redhat.openshift 4.0.0

I installed required python modules too.
Basically, I have an ansible role that I call from a main playbook.
Ansible role:
cat roles/ocp-roles/tasks/ldap-sync.yaml  | grep -v "#"
---
- name: Sync a group from LDAP server
  community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync:
    sync_config: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/msaka/roles/ocp-roles/files/ldap-config.yaml') | from_yaml }}"

/root/msaka/roles/ocp-roles/files/ldap-config.yaml file is the standard yaml file to synchrnioze LDAP accounts, an example can be found here:
Ldap sync definition
Here is the playbook:
cat main.yml | grep -v "#"
---
- name: Connect to OpenShift Cluster
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes


  tasks:
    - name: Log in using kubeconfig
      include_role:
        name: ocp-roles
        tasks_from: ocp-connect

    - name: Sync LDAP groups
      include_role:
        name: ocp-roles
        tasks_from: ldap-sync

    - name: Log out cluster
      include_role:
        name: ocp-roles
        tasks_from: ocp-logout


First task connects to cluster and retrieve a token. Second task is supposed to apply configuration in /root/msaka/roles/ocp-roles/files/ldap-config.yaml file to synchronize LDAP group in OpenShift identity provider. 3rd one will revoke the token and logout.
But while running the playbook 2nd task raise following error:

An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full
traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: not all arguments
converted during string formatting fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
{"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call
last):\n  File
"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1721924868.9662192-3650208-263793937055620/AnsiballZ_openshift_adm_groups_sync.py",
line 107, in \n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File
"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1721924868.9662192-3650208-263793937055620/AnsiballZ_openshift_adm_groups_sync.py",
line 99, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path,
ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File
"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1721924868.9662192-3650208-263793937055620/AnsiballZ_openshift_adm_groups_sync.py",
line 47, in invoke_module\n
runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.community.okd.plugins.modules.openshift_adm_groups_sync', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible_collections.community.okd.plugins.modules.openshift_adm_groups_sync', _modlib_path=modlib_path),\n  File "", line 226, in run_module\n  File "", line 98, in _run_module_code\n
File "", line 88, in _run_code\n  File
"/tmp/ansible_community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync_payload_qstpd6qv/ansible_community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/okd/plugins/modules/openshift_adm_groups_sync.py",
line 227, in \n  File
"/tmp/ansible_community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync_payload_qstpd6qv/ansible_community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/okd/plugins/modules/openshift_adm_groups_sync.py",
line 223, in main\n  File
"/tmp/ansible_community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync_payload_qstpd6qv/ansible_community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/okd/plugins/module_utils/openshift_common.py", line 97, in run_module\n  File
"/tmp/ansible_community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync_payload_qstpd6qv/ansible_community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/okd/plugins/module_utils/openshift_groups.py", line 507, in execute_module\n  File
"/tmp/ansible_community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync_payload_qstpd6qv/ansible_community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/okd/plugins/module_utils/openshift_groups.py", line 416, in synchronize\n  File
"/tmp/ansible_community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync_payload_qstpd6qv/ansible_community.okd.openshift_adm_groups_sync_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/okd/plugins/module_utils/openshift_ldap.py",
line 607, in get_username_for_entry\nTypeError: not all arguments
converted during string formatting\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg":
"MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

If you can help / post a working example of this module, it would be great.
I'm open to any other module / proposition the make it work. I also think to use bash scripts instead of dealing with these problems. I would like to get your opinions too.
